# openURL method not getting called when updating app after first download with dynamic link

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When I update my app with a new version by building over it the openURL method is called. But when I click on a dynamic link and do an update after that the openURL method isnt called anymore.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

This is the code where I want to do things with the openURL method/

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application

        openURL:(NSURL *)url

        options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {



// Sends the URL to the current authorization flow (if any) which will

// process it if it relates to an authorization response.

if ([_currentAuthorizationFlow resumeAuthorizationFlowWithURL:url]) {

    _currentAuthorizationFlow = nil;

    return YES;

}



FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];

NSString *userID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xx"];

NSString *firstTimeAppOpened = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xxx"];


if (dynamicLink != nil) {

    if ([dynamicLink.url.absoluteString length] != 0) {

        NSLog(@"App opened with link: %@", dynamicLink);



        NSString *snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URLScheme: Received dynamic firebase link: %@", dynamicLink.url.absoluteString];

        NSString *category = @"DYNAMIC_LINK";

        NSString *pathFromURL = [dynamicLink.url.absoluteString lastPathComponent];


        [SiteConnector sendAuditWithSnippet:snippet inCategory:category];



        NSString *firstTimeAppOpened = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FirstTimeAppOpened"];



        if ([dynamicLink.url.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"murat"].location == NSNotFound) {

            [self dynamicLinkBehaviour:pathFromURL second:dynamicLink.url absolutePath:nil];

        } else {

            if (firstTimeAppOpened == nil) {

                [self onboardingDynamicLink:dynamicLink.url.absoluteString];

            }

        }

    }

    else {

        if (userID == nil && firstTimeAppOpened == nil) {

            [self openWelcomeScreen];

        }

    }

}



NSString *valueToSave = @"yes";

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"FirstTimeLoggedIn"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application

                                                      openURL:url

                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]

                                                   annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```

}

Comment: would you like to open an url using openURL?

Comment: @SandipGill Yes, when the app is started for the first time I need to do an check. But the openURL method is only called when I download the app and also when I do an update(by installing on top of the previous installation). But when I download the app with the firebase dynamic link it works but not when I do an update on top of it.

Comment: So the firebase dynamic link does something strange. It does not open the openURL method after doing an update above of the download that was doen with the firebase dynamic link.

Comment: ok can you please share the code ?

Comment: @SandipGill I have added the openURL method into this "question".

Comment: ok i have answered please try that code if it works. (Y)

Comment: @SandipGill Do I need to place that code in my method? Because the method isnt called..

Comment: yes you can place the code where you want to open your url

Comment: you are using objective c But answer is in swift

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: @SandipGill Thank you for your help. But my problem isnt solved yet. The problem is that my method doesnt activate after clicking on a dynamic link and downloading the app and after that rebuilding the app.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what operations you are performing, what happening and what you expect to happens? Firebase Dynamic Links will call method openURL: only when you tap on dynamic link while App is not installed, download (or otherwise install the App), and launch the App for the first time. If App is already installed when you tap on dynamic link, will be called method application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: . Ensure you followed guide here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov What if I download the app for the first time with a dynamic link and afther that doing an update? Will the openURL method be called(after doing an update) ?

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov So I download the app for the first time with the dynamic link without having the app already on my phone. After that I do an update. But then it fails to call it. But when I dont download the app with the dynamic link and do an update, the openURL method is called. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: @IOSporgrammerIOS Do I understand this correctly: 1. While App is not installed tap on dynamic link in Safari on iPhone, tap on OPEN button in opened page; 2. Install App; 3. Launch App for the first time; 4. openURL: method not called but the method expected to be called? If correct, please open Firebase Support bug and we will figure out what went wrong. Please run method [FIRDynamicLinks performDiagnosticsWithCompletion:nil]; and provide output of this method in your ticket.

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov 
1 : click on dynamic link and go to the appstore with it
2 : build project (so it looks like i downloaded it from the appstore)
3 : the openURL method is called
4 : Build project over the current one (to simulate an app update)
5 : openURL method is not called

If i do those steps but not opening (and after that building) appstore with a dynamic link, the openURL method will be called at step 5.

Comment: @IOSporgrammerIOS Got it. openURL: will not be called in step 5 because openURL was already called in step 3. Update is not counted as new install. openURL: will be called only once per install.

Answer (score 0):

`openURL` is only called when an app is opened by a URI scheme i.e. `fb://`. Firebase uses **Universal Links** in most cases and apps opened by universal links trigger the `continue userActivity` protocol function. You can refer to their docs for that code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  guard let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
    return false
  }
  let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
    // ...
  }

  return handled
}
```

This is one reason why I recommend using [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking) since they do their handling in one callback regardless of whether it's a URI scheme or Universal link.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the openURL is called everytime the first time the app is installed. So my questions still stands.. I need this method to active or not active. Not doing both..

Answer (score -1):

Hello @IOSporgrammerIOS Please try this.

```
 
var yourUrl = NSURL(string:"url_String")!

 if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(yourUrl as URL){

     UIApplication.shared.openURL(yourUrl as URL)

  }
```

Objective C

```
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

     [application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
   {
        if (success) {

            NSLog(@"Opened url");
       }
 }];
```